# How can I assign event.currentTarget to a variable?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to use multiple images in my flash script and instead of writing tons of code I want to get the 'currentTarget' and assign a variable name to it so I can tweenlite it . Instead of me naming all the instances I thought the following would work but it doesn't. Can anybody give me some pointers , thanks

```
wedding.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, pan_over);

function pan_over(e: MouseEvent): void {
  var ct: string = Event.currentTarget.name;

  TweenLite.to(ct, 1, {
    scaleX: 1.4,
    scaleY: 1.03
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
    wedding.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, pan_over) ;

    function pan_over(e:MouseEvent):void{
       TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget, 1, {scaleX:1.4, scaleY:1.03} ) ;
    }
```

Comment: This will work. The issue, as shortstick points out below, is that you are trying to pass a String into your TweenLite call. It's one thing to pass MyObject and another thing to pass a String that says "MyObject" - does that make sense?

That said - just use e.currentTarget, there's no need to recast it as anything else.

Answer (score -1):

TweenLite uses an object, not the named reference, therefore by passing to it the name `MovieClip1` for example you are not passing the string but the previously constructed object.
if you want to store the currentTarget for later then you should be using something like:

```
function pan_over(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var ct:Object = Event.currentTarget;
    TweenLite.to(ct, 1, {scaleX:1.4, scaleY:1.03} ) ;
}
```